# How to send Id and retrieve data related to that ID from database using Web API in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, rest, webapi

I want to send CatID as user from client side and in server side I need to accept that and send back response to the client catName, catDes, catPic relevant to entered ID.

**Below code is used to send Data to client.** I want to receive req. from client and send back relevant response to client, this needs to done via Web API.

```cs
public class AddcatController : ApiController
    {

        [HttpPost]

        public HttpResponseMessage PostCat(Catergory category)
        {
            using (var db = new NorthwindEntities())
            {
                db.Categories.Add(new Category()
                {
                    CategoryID = category.catId,
                    CategoryName = category.catName,
                    Description = category.catDes,
                    Picture = category.catPic


                });

                db.SaveChanges();

            }
            //return OK;
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this, but you would change the ActionResult and return methods to your scenario.

```
[HttpGet]

//You can change it to HttpResponseMessage
public ActionResult GetCat(int catId)
{
    Category resp = null;
    using (var db = new NorthwindEntities())
    {
        resp = db.Categories.FirstOrDefault(f => f.CategoryID == catId);

    }

    if(resp == null)
    {
        return NotFound("Category not found"); //You can change it to HttpResponseMessage similar method
    }
    //return OK;
    return Ok(resp);
}
```